# How to enable the Ubuntu Tweak login settings section?

Tags: ubuntu-tweak

I have installed Ubuntu Tweak and found its `Tweaks - Startup - Login settings` section disabled (I can open it but everything is shaded out and nothing works inside). How can it be enabled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the next picture. Do you see a Unlock button. That's it!

[image: Ubuntu Tweak]

Comment: Oh, I see now. I didn't notice it as it doesn't appear for other sections. Thanks.

Comment: "I don't have this button. There is nothing on its place." -yes you have it :))