# Ubuntu keeps reverting to botched wallpaper

Tags: lightdm, desktop-background, unity-greeter

I've got a pesky problem. Since I started using Ubuntu I've been playing around with the theming of it, and now -something- keeps forcing itself on boot. I want to know how to debug it, and/or find the source.

The problem is this: Whenever I boot my laptop the default login-wallpaper and the wallpaper after login is a botched, cut-up/repeated image that (I think) is the result of `nitrogen`.

I now run the command `nitrogen --restore` and it fixes the wallpaper. Now when I lock the machine or logout, I see a correct wallpaper. So everything is fine after I once restore the wallpaper.

So it's a small nuisance but it's bothering me nonetheless: What keeps rewriting my desktop wallpaper on boot? How do I find it out?

**What I know:**
Whenever I disable Nitrogen (and enable desktop icons) the correct set wallpaper applies a second after login, but it still keeps the botched login-wallpaper.

**What I already tried:**
Reset Nitrogen, using things like [Ubuntu Tweak](https://askubuntu.com/questions/291744/how-to-enable-the-ubuntu-tweak-login-settings-section) and commands [like these](https://askubuntu.com/questions/694202/change-the-background-of-the-login-screen/694370).
I feel like I've already tried tons of possible ways to (re)set the greeter wallpaper, but something keeps forcing it on boot.

Now I'm not afraid to dive in the technicals, though I can be considered a Ubuntu-noob (only a few months on the system). How, where and why can I find out what exactly is happening? Like is there a way to print all boot commands in a way that would point me in the right direction? Am I missing something obvious? Whelp!

Comment: It's not result of Nitrogen, but of the icons setting ( which in reality simply disables the default file manager from creating the special desktop window, and that's what contains the wallpaper). Whenever I have desktop icons disabled,  the wallpaper also is disabled, so the login screen background will be copied through to the desktop.  Is there are reason why you keep desktop icons off ?

Comment: I know that, I only (want to) use Nitrogen to have multi-monitor wallpapers, and Nitrogen doesn't work when the icons are enabled; that's why those are disabled. But even when I enable the icons and set the default wallpaper-functionality, the login wallpaper still is the same botched image, no matter how many ways or times I set another.

Comment: actually, i just had a scripting idea, that might help you. Check back with me in couple of days, might even finish it by tomorrow, OK ?

Comment: Sure, sounds good!

Comment: @Serg: Any news? :D

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy ^^^^____^^^^

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix  Ooops :)